# AngularJs template with conditional attribute

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

**Task:** create template which has conditional attributes, which changes depending on model value.

**Problem:** When I set template using directive, its attributes are set once and not changes any more.

Here is my code:

**Derective:**

```
loginApp.directive('validationIcon', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            validatedField: '=',
        },
        template: '<ng-include src="contentUrl"/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("validatedField.$touched", function () {
                if (scope.validatedField.$touched) {
                    scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                        scope.contentUrl = '../../pages/templates/validation-icon-tplt.html';
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        replace: true
    };
}]);
```

**template:**

```
<i ng-class="{'fa fa-lg fa-times-circle': {{validatedField.$invalid}}, 'fa fa-lg fa-check-circle' : {{validatedField.$valid}} }" 
   ng-style="{{validatedField.$invalid}} ?{color: 'red'}: {color: 'green'}"/>

element:
        <form action="#" novalidate method="post" name="regForm" ng-submit="submit()">
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Username" name="userName" ng-model="userName" required autofocus/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><validation-icon validated-field=regForm.userName></validation-icon>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Maybe someone can tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: about which attributes you are talking about..? other thing is you have mistaken in ng-style directive..it should be `<i ng-class="{'fa fa-lg fa-times-circle': validatedField.$invalid, 'fa fa-lg fa-check-circle' : validatedField.$valid }" 
   ng-style="validatedField.$invalid ?{color: 'red'}: {color: 'green'}"/>`

Comment: you are breaking the golden rule of not using an object in `ng-model`. Fix that first. 2 way bindings get broken easily in templates using primitives

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar, thank you the brackets was the problem,just still do not know why in one cases they are needed and in other not.

Comment: @charlietfl, to say truth I didn't understand, maybe you can provide some code with explanation?